# If B can be obtained from A by a sequence of elementary row operations then the transforming matrix is not uniquely determined by A and B

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> If $B$ can be obtained from $A$ by a sequence of elementary row operations, show that the transforming matrix, $P$ is not uniquely determined by $A$ and $B$ in general.

In case $A=B=0$, it is obvious that the sequence of elementary row operations is not unique. Hence, $A$ and $B$ do not determine a unique $P$.

> How to prove this for a general case when $A,B\ne0$?

In case $A$ is of full row rank, I can see that $P$ is unique although the sequence of elementary row operations is not (the sequence need not be unique follows from the first line, which I want the general proof of).

This is because :
$A$ is of full row rank $\Rightarrow A$ has a right inverse, say $A^{-1}_R$

$\therefore PA=QA\Rightarrow PAA^{-1}_R=QAA^{-1}_R\Rightarrow PI=QI\Rightarrow P=Q$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ is singular then there is a non-zero transforming matrix $Q$ such that $QA=0$.

Then $PA=(P+Q)A$ for any matrix $P$.

Hence, $A$ and $B$ do not determine a unique $P$.

Comment: If $A$ is non invertible then it is singular and I proceed with your method. In case $A$ is invertible that means $A$ has full row rank, for which $P$ is unique.. right?

Comment: Yes, you are right.